# Change Values of jquery plugin real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to change the value of an attribute of this plugin.  In this case, the draggable value - each time I press a link.  I really have any idea how to proceed.

This is my script:

```
<script>
    $('#image').reel({
    images:      'mini/###.jpg',
    frames:      20,
    frame:       14,
    rows:        6,
    row:         3,
    draggable:   false
    });
</script>
```

This is my html:

```
<a href="javascript:prova();">prova</a>

<!-- Or Javascript alternative: -->

<img id="image" src="mini.jpg" width="200" height="200" />


<script type="text/javascript">

     function prova() { 
          $('#image').triggerHandler('frameChange',2);
          console.log("ssss");
          /*
          $('#image').reel('images', 'mini2/###.jpg');
          console.log("qqqqqqq");
          $('#image').reel('draggable', 'true');
          console.log("qqqqqqq")
          *//*
          console.log($('#image').reel('frame')); 
          console.log($('#image').reel('row'));
          $('#image').reel('draggable','true'); 
          $('#image').reel('frame',1); 
          console.log($('#image').reel('frame')); 

       }


</script>
```

The last is the script where i try to change the value of draggable, any suggestion?

Comment: What is your issue? Are you asking how to add click functionality or just how to change the values in the plugin? are you using the reel plugin or what plugin are you using? Normally you can change options using a new object literal. Something along the likes of:   `$('#image').reel({draggable:, 'true', images:'mini2/###.jpg'});`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes i'm using the reel plugin. My issue is that I need to be able the user to enable or unabled the draggable option, I thought to make it with a button but I don't know how Change the value in real time.. Now I will try your suggestion.

Comment: It doesn't work because doing in that way i regenerate the object (my set of images) , instead i need to change only the draggable status. I think that maybe i have to modify the reel.js and create a function to manage the draggable status.